# How to press [WINDOW] + [UpArrow] keys together, using Sikuli or Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I need to press <kbd>WINDOW</kbd> + <kbd>UpArrow</kbd>.

At first attempt I have tried with **`sikuli`** by :-

```
s1.type(Key.WIN + Key.UP);
```

But it only press <kbd>WINDOW</kbd> and <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> buttons, **but separately**.

By selenium I have try with `Actions` class but I have found there is no key available to press <kbd>WINDOW</kbd> button there.

Comment: I have done my operation using Robot Class for same.

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);

Comment: For using Robot class, what jar should be added? And what package is needed?

Comment: You do not need to import any additional java library.
You just need to to have jdk version equal or greater than 1.7


import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In sikuli, if you want to simulate pressing and holding one button, while then typing another, use `type(TheKeyDoingTheAction, KeyModifier.TheKeyYoureHoldingDown` It's written like this:

```
type(Key.UP, KeyModifier.WIN) #This is the one from your question
```

Here are a few other common examples:

```
type("c", KeyModifier.CTRL) #copies whatever is selected to the clipboard
type(Key.LEFT, KeyModifier.ALT) #goes back one page in most web browsers
```

Here's an exerpt from the [sikuli docs](http://doc.sikuli.org/keys.html):

"The modifier constants can be combined to the modifier parameter by either using “+” or “|”, if more than one key modifier is needed.

```
type(Key.ESC, KeyModifier.CTRL + KeyModifier.ALT)
# or equivalent -
type(Key.ESC, KeyModifier.CTRL | KeyModifier.ALT)
```

They should only be used in the modifiers parameter with functions like type(), rightClick(), etc.
They should never be used with keyDown() or keyUp()."

Comment: How to click WIN + M key for minimizing the all window by Sikuli with Java?

Comment: @RiponAlWasim type("m", KeyModifier.WIN) I believe, in the Sikuli IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot  autoKarma. The code is working for me well. Actually, I am using Sikuli with Java in Eclipse IDE.