# C# and Selenium; Possible to press Windows key?

Tags: c#, selenium

I would like to move my browser window to the left or right side of the screen. Manually I would press[WINDOW] + [LeftArrow] (or [RightArrow]) to achieve this.

I've read [this one but it's for Java (see comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281027/how-to-press-window-uparrow-keys-together-using-sikuli-or-selenium#) but I can't find a way to press the windows key when using C#.

My best option seems to be:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(x-coord, y-coord);
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(myWidth,myHeight);
```

but seems to be a bit fiddly, and I'm sure there is a better way.

I have also tried:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(Keys.   )
```

Then Keys doesn't have the windows key...

Comment: why,`Keys.LWin` is the left logo key, and `Keys.RWin` the right, respectively.

Comment: Your original method is good

Comment: Why are going to press windows key while you can simply use JavaScript `scrollInToView()` to reach the element???

Comment: @dlatikay hmm, I don't get Keys.LWin nor Keys.RWin. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I'm not trying to reach an element, I'm trying to move the browser window to the left (or right) side of the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like to go for they `SendKeys` approach, sending key combinations that include the Windows logo key is not straightforward. The equivalent for the Windows logo key alone would be <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. While that can be simulated, <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> would just open the start menu (or whatever they call it now in Windows 10), and then send another left arrow.

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10367832/1132334) there is a solution.

Comment: Thank you! I have not tried yet, but seems just like the thing i wanted! And apparently I need to work on my google skills since I did not find it myself...

Answer (score 0):

`dllatikay`'s answer is very helpful for understanding how things work. I will just add a working example - how to maximize browser window when using Selenium:

```
 // Install-Package InputSimulator in package manager
 var inputSim = new InputSimulator();
 // WinKey + Up maximizes current focused window
 inputSim.Keyboard.ModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.LWIN, VirtualKeyCode.UP);
```