# Key press (Windows+D) by Selenium WebDriver Actions

Tags: java, selenium, keypress

Is there a way to perform a <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> key press by Selenium WebDriver Actions?

I can do almost all the other combinations of key pressings with Actions but couldn't find the way to simulate a <kbd>Windows</kbd> key press.

It should be something like this:

```
action.keyDown(Windows).sendKeys((String.valueOf('\u0036'))).keyUp(Windows).perform()
```

I also know how to do this with Robot but I'm looking for resolutions by Actions.

**UPD:**

None of so far suggested already existing questions with their answers *DOES NOT* provide answer to this problem!

So please do not flag my question as duplicate until you found an answer, tried is and found it answering my question!

Comment: I believe you can find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677648/c-sharp-and-selenium-possible-to-press-windows-key

Comment: I already saw that question and the answer there.
I do now think this helps me.
But I will try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# and Selenium; Possible to press Windows key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677648/c-sharp-and-selenium-possible-to-press-windows-key)

Comment: Try this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver

Comment: @JeffC and musikreck! 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677648/c-sharp-and-selenium-possible-to-press-windows-key DOES NOT provide answer to my question!
The https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver too.
Please remove you "duplicate" flag since it's not a duplicate.

Comment: The Windows key is not a key but is instead a combination of keys. This is explained in the dup that I linked. You need to put the different code attempts you have made so we can see what you have and have not tried and include the results, error messages, etc.

Comment: I wrote I can do this by Robot. Do you want me to put that working code here?
This will explain you better the question I'm asking?
I tried several combinations of keys with Actions but this simply does not do the action I'm looking for. No errors, no crashes.