# Left Minimize a Selenium Browser Window with Python

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26281027/how-to-press-window-uparrow-keys-together-using-sikuli-or-selenium#) except that it's in Java.

Specifically, I want to automatically **left** maximize a selenium browser in Python. I'm using Windows. Is there is a simple way to do that?

The answer there references a package called Sikuli, with which I'm not familiar. A bit of trial and error and Googling indicates installing that package is a bit complicated. If possible, I would like to avoid doing that for just this one simple task.